# Javascript replace character if already exists

Tags: javascript

I want to limit the user from entering more than one decimal into a number. I know how to check if they already entered 1 decimal, but how do I continue from there, to check if they enter a second decimal and replace it with an empty string?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Can you show us some code.

Comment: Can't you just use `<input type="text" maxlength="1" />` instead? It'll automatically allow the user to type only 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript. I chose jQuery.

Listen to every single keypress. Every time the user presses down on a key, check it. If it's the second decimal for that input, prevent the keypress.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#test').on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.which == 190 && $(event.target).val().indexOf('.') > -1) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="test">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Javascript solution: https://jsfiddle.net/xrqe121e/3/.

This loop:

```
for (var i=0, flag=false; i<input.length; i++) {
    var isDigit = isNumber(input[i]);
    if (!(isDigit && flag)) {
        str+=input[i];
    }
    if (isDigit) flag = true;
}
```

Goes over the input received and adds to the output every character that is not a digit besides the first digit.